# How to interrupt Kotlin suspend function in coroutines and start over

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

so long story short, I have java/kotlin project running and I'm looking for a way to cancel kotlin suspend function and start coroutine over if circumstances changes. in my code I could have 100 players ( coroutines ) running at the same time with suspend functions etc. and hourly or every x time Java calls some of those players. when it does I need coroutine to stop that suspend function and start coroutine again. code looks like below:

```
internal suspend fun update() {
    doesCoolStuff()
    goesSomewhere()
    delay 20sec
    GoesSomewhereElse()
    delay 60sec
    GoesSomewhereElsex2()
    delay 100sec
    }

private suspend fun GoesSomewhereElse() {
doesThings()
delay 2 mins
}
```

etc. my problem is that when java calls player which is inside of suspend function in delay it does the action from java and than stands and waits for delay to run out before starts doing CoolStuff which is at beginning of coroutine.
so Basically I need something to interrupt suspend function and cancel all delay and starts over coroutine. like "return" function which can be used in coroutine to return to beginning and start over just from Java.

EDIT:
when time comes and Java calls the player. it does a couple of other things like teleports player, changes name, add him to a event team. and if that player at the time is in middle of doing something it's fine it resets couroutine start from beginning where I have an if player is in event it does Stuff.
which works well, however if player is in middle of 3 minutes delay, it stands in event for remaining time of those 3 minutes. before it goes back to beginning of coroutine where it realizes that it is in event and have to do stuff.

Comment: We need to know more about this Java player. Does it provide any way to interrupt the action? Maybe you can specify the exact library or class.

Comment: just updated more info, regarding java call. hopefully it helps.

Comment: That doesn't answer what I was getting at. Does the API of the player permit you to interrupt what you started through a method call? You can cancel a coroutine, but if the state of the player doesn't cooperate with cancelation, then the player will still be doing whatever you told it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep reference to `Job`:

```kotlin
var job: Job? = null


job?.cancel()
job = coroutineScope.launch { aSuspendFunction() }
```

Comment: I was not able to use this outside of kotlin part of the project. and in this case I would need interruption when Java side of project does the action. Also ideally it shouldn't cancel whole coroutine, just interrupt suspend function and start over.